# How can I make Slidingbar's SLIDING_CONTENT work in ActionbarSherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

SLIDING_CONTENT parameter means only the content of the Activity sliding when touching,titlebar stays.

When I import ActionbarSherlock, I found it did not work well.

I saw the source code

this is a part of code in class SlidingMenu (attachToActivity)

```
    case SLIDING_CONTENT:
        // take the above view out of
        View content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        ViewGroup contentParent = (ViewGroup) content.getParent();
        contentParent.removeView(content);
        contentParent.addView(this, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setContent(content);
        // save people from having transparent backgrounds
        if (content.getBackground() == null)
            content.setBackgroundResource(background);
        break;
    }
```

it works with the Activity which contains titlebar, but you know abs customized titlebar.....

how can i alter something to make SLIDING_CONTENT alive?
thx a lot!!

Comment: witch activity you are extending ?

Comment: I extended SherlockActivity~

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem , how fast i am~ 
:)

Only create a new constructor

```
public void attachToActivity(Activity activity, int slideStyle,int id)
```

add a new param 'id' id represent the main activity layout id.

and then change

```
View content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

to

```
View content  = activity.findViewById(id);
```

and change another function which is calling the old attachToActivity (It is easy)

if you have any question, email me [smallbeardict@163.com](http://mailto%3asmallbeardict@163.com)